# Why am I getting the "EDBClient: Mismatch in datapacket" exception?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, datasnap

I'm often getting this exception "EDBClient: Mismatch in datapacket"
when I call ApplyUpdates on a particular ClientDataSet.

I can't reproduce on my machine and I think it started after upgrading
to Delphi 2010, because this code is untouched for a long time.

An additional information is that I don't use midas.dll, I compile MidasLib unit with my project.

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: i suspect they changed the component, but not the manual ,to reflect the changed.

Answer (score 0):

Check midas.dll version

Comment: I don't use midas.dll, I compile MidasLib with my project.